# DeadLock a nível de projeto Conceitual, modelagem entidade-relacionamento (MER)

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, entidade-relacionamento

A nível de projeto conceitual podemos utilizar a abordagem (modelagem entidade relacionamento (MER)) para descrever o comportamento das futuras tabelas que surgirão no projeto lógico. Dentro desse contexto surgiu uma dúvida.

Na modelagem entidade e relacionamento (MER) existe a cardinalidade 1:M

Gostaria de saber se existe algum exemplo real desse tipo de relacionamento (entre duas entidades com essa cardinalidade).

Veja o desenho do MER, Exemplo: [image: link de um desenho MER]

Caso exista, então não temos um princípio de deadlock? já que uma depende que a outra exista primeiro e vice-versa.

Como resolver o deadlock das entidades que possuem esse tipo de relacionamento nos dois lados?

Sempre que temos 1 como cardinalidade mínima em um dos lados, indica que existe um grau de dependência total ou parcial entre as entidades envolvidas?

Acabei de ler o capítulo 7 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: Sistemas de Banco de dados 6ª edição, autores: Elmasri, Ramez
Navathe, Shamkant B. Ano: 2011

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode aceitar a inconsistência eventual numa modelagem física `[0,N]` como na [resposta do @VictorStafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250722/64969). Ou então usar um banco de dados que aceita inconsistências no meio de transações. Essa opção não é comum, eu particularmente só conheço o SQLite que faz isso.

Como proceder nesse caso? Bem, no SQLite eles chamam essa consistência de chave estrangeira como "chave estrangeira deferida". Está na seção 4.2 [desse artigo](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) explicando sobre chaves estrangeiras.

O conceito da "chave deferida" é:

> Se estou dentro de uma transação, então ocasionalmente a consistência será alcançada, não preciso verificar a cada instante se tudo está consistente

Normalmente o conceito utilizado com "chave estrangeira" é o que o SQLite chama de "chave estrangeira imediata":

> Não importa onde esteja nem pra onde vou, tudo precisa estar consistente a todo e qualquer instante!!!

Nesse modelo de consistência por "chave estrangeira deferida", basta iniciar uma transação antes das inserções e então commitar quando se termina de operar.

Eu acho particularmente valioso essa modelagem de consistência apenas após o término de transação quando se tem dados circulares.

Imagine que você está modelando uma equidna. Esses animais estranhos, não bastando ser um dos poucos mamíferos ovíparos, possuem um [pênis de múltiplas cabeças](https://youtu.be/_8hp_4V32Ow). E os machos usam essas cabeças de modo muito interessante: eles revezam qual cabeça vai ser usado para copular, de modo que todas as cabeças são usadas antes de se repetir uma delas.

> **ERRATA**: a equidna não faz revezamento da cabeça do pênis como eu havia citado no parágrafo acima. Na verdade, ela expele pelos dutos seminais até duas levas de sêmen por cabeças distintas, mas vale pelo exercício mental

Para aqueles que não conhecem esses seres esquisitos, com corpo de ouriço e língua de tamanduá que bota ovos e dá de mamar a seus descendentes, segue sua foto (cortesia cavada pelo @Bacco): [link para a equidna](https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/dc8e15aba92b1f38eca871d4b7896991?width=1024&x.jpg)

Nesse caso, poderíamos modelar assim:

```
create table equidna (
  id int primary key,
  tag varchar(50) not null
)

create table penis_equidna (
  id int primary key,
  equidna_id int not null,
  prox_penis_id int not null,
  em_uso int not null default 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (equidna_id) REFERENCES equidna(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (prox_penis_id) REFERENCES penis_equidna(id) NOT DEFERRABLE
)
```

Note que estou aqui criando uma lista circular de pênises de equidnas. Para atualizar qual será o próximo pênis a estar em uso para a próxima cópula da equidna 13, basta executar o seguinte update:

```
WITH p_em_uso AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    prox_penis_id,
    anterior_penis_id,
    equidna_id
  FROM
    penis_equidna
  WHERE
    em_uso = 1
)
UPDATE penis_equidna
SET
  em_uso = CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM p_em_uso WHERE p_em_uso.prox_penis_id = penis_equidna.id AND p_em_uso.equidna_id = penis_equidna.equidna_id) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
WHERE
  equidna_id = 13
```

> Consulta não verificada ainda, espero verificar em breve e corrigir todo qualquer e eventual erro nela contido

No caso, para cadastrar a equidna 13 e seus 4 pênis, teria sido necessário isso:

```
INSERT INTO equidna(id, tag) VALUES (13, 'abc')(

BEGIN; -- começa uma transação SQLite

INSERT INTO penis_equidna(id, equidna_id, prox_penis_id, em_uso) VALUES (1, 13, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO penis_equidna(id, equidna_id, prox_penis_id, em_uso) VALUES (2, 13, 4, 0), (4, 13, 3, 0), (3, 13, 1, 0)

COMMIT;
```

Note que a consistência só será alcançada quando a última linha for inserida, fechando portanto o círculo.

---

Dito esse modelo de consistência, eu não consigo modelar de nenhum jeito óbvio sem usar `check constraints` de modo abusivo um relacionamento de `[1,N]` para `[1,N]`. Até acho que seria melhor permitir essa inconsistência do zero. Não me parece certo depois de remover uma casa eu ser obrigado a remover uma pessoa (usando a modelagem da resposta do @VictorStafusa).

## Um caso real dessa modelagem

Estava de bobeira no chat quando o [@gato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/27190/gato) surgiu com um problema de modelagem de estrutura no banco de dados (início mais ou menos [aqui](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41467079#41467079)).

O problema dele eu identifiquei mais ou menos como o seguinte:

> Tenho sensores de incêndio em diversos locais. Por exemplo, o km 12 (no estado de SP) da BR-116 é o local identificado por `1`, já o km 13 dela é o local identificado por `2`.
>
> Esses sensores disparam alertas, que devem ficar armazenados no banco. Esses alertas vem com o identificador do sensor que o disparou e a intensidade do incêndio identificado. Porém, em tese, um mesmo ponto de incêndio pode disparar alarmes em diversos sensores no mesmo local. Então, cada local só pode ter um ponto de incêndio "ligado" por vez, e todo alerta se refere sempre a um ponto de incêndio.

Eu consegui inferir a seguinte modelagem no modelo MER:

[image: local tem muitos sensores; sensor dispara diversos alertas; um ou mais alertas se referem a um ponto de incêndio]

No caso, também detectei um detalhe importante: a inserção de um `alerta` pode gerar um novo `ponto_queimada`! Como se fosse um gatilho de criação!

Então, como fazer isso? Bem, pensei em realmente usar um gatilho. Poderia ter sido um procedimento em SQL ou então alguma solução programática a nível de aplicação. `Trigger` me pareceu mais natural, entretanto.

A ideia da minha `trigger` é:

1. verificar se já existe um ponto de queimada naquela região
   esse ponto de queimada **não pode** ter sido contido
2. se não existir esse ponto de queimada, inserir ele
3. agora o ponto de queimada simplesmente existe (se não existia antes, agora existe), então posso inserir o alerta apontando para o alerta correto

Eu pensei nessa `trigger` substituindo uma inserção. No caso, eu pensei em ter a `alertas_view_insercao`, em que ela não teria a informação de `id_ponto_queimada`/chave estrangeira para ponto de queimada. Segue um pseudocódigo para essa `trigger` ([original](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41467911#41467911)):

```
create trigger insteadof insert on alertas_view_insercao as
begin trigger

insert into ponto_queimada
select
     'N'as CONTIDA
   ... informações
where not exists (
     select top 1 1
     from ponto_queimada pq
        inner join alerta a on pq.id_ponto_queimada = a.id_ponto_queimada
        inner join sensor s on a.id_sensor = s.id_sensor
        inner join local l on l.id_local = s.id_local
     where pq.contida = 'N' and l.id_local = inserted.id_local
);

with q as ( --se não existia um ponto_queimada antes, agora existe...
     select top 1 pq.id_ponto_queimada
     from ponto_queimada pq
        inner join alerta a on pq.id_ponto_queimada = a.id_ponto_queimada
        inner join sensor s on a.id_sensor = s.id_sensor
        inner join local l on l.id_local = s.id_local
     where pq.contida ='N' and l.id_local = inserted.id_local
)
inser into alerta
select
     q.id_ponto_queimada,
   ... informações
from q


end trigger
```

A ideia da `trigger` na `view` é:

1. como é uma `view`, o "usuário" só pode informar as colunas que **EU** quero
2. por usar `insteadof`, o efeito da inserção é substituído pelo conteúdo da `trigger`

Diversos bancos suportam operações em `views` ([SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html), SQL Server, etc). O momento `insteadof` é conhecido como [`instead of`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger) (com espaço) pelo SQLite.

Com essa `trigger`, ao registrar um novo `alerta` através da `alertas_view_insercao`, o próprio banco se preocupará em informar a qual `ponto_queimada` esse alerta se refere. O banco mesmo verifica se existe um `ponto_queimada` adequado e, na sua não existência, criará um novo.

Comment: Acho que você deveria ter procurado um exemplo menos controverso do que ficar falando de pênis de equidnas.

Comment: Parece-me que o exemplo das equidnas é uma boa para demostrar relacionamentos recursivos ou reflexivos, o exemplo da pergunta não faz referência a essa situação.

Comment: @JonathasB.Cavalcante e o uso da chave deferida? Viu como ela evita o _deadlock_?

Comment: Sim @JeffersonQuesado , apesar de já ter trabalhado com sqlite eu não havia dado a devida atenção a chave deferida, ficou muito boa a explicação.

Comment: @JonathasB.C., adicionei um caso recente que peguei da modelagem `1..[1,n]`. A solução foi através de um gatilho para manter o banco consistente

Comment: Ficou massa o exemplo, vlw @JeffersonQuesado

Answer (score 6):

Você tem que olhar para o modelo físico. Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE casa (
    id INT,
    endereco VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE pessoa (
    id INT,
    nome VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE moradia (
    id_pessoa INT,
    id_casa INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_pessoa, id_casa),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_pessoa) REFERENCES pessoa (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_casa) REFERENCES casa (id),
);

INSERT INTO casa (id, endereco) VALUES (1, 'Avenida do código, 1233');
INSERT INTO casa (id, endereco) VALUES (2, 'Rua do SQL, 478');
INSERT INTO casa (id, endereco) VALUES (3, 'Avenida do banco de dados, 32');

INSERT INTO pessoa (id, nome) VALUES (1, 'Carlos');
INSERT INTO pessoa (id, nome) VALUES (2, 'Maria');
INSERT INTO pessoa (id, nome) VALUES (3, 'Pedro');
INSERT INTO pessoa (id, nome) VALUES (4, 'Julia');

-- Carlos mora na Avenida do código.
INSERT INTO moradia (id_pessoa, id_casa) VALUES (1, 1);

-- Pedro também mora na Avenida do código, na mesma casa que Carlos.
INSERT INTO moradia (id_pessoa, id_casa) VALUES (3, 1);

-- Maria mora na rua do SQL.
INSERT INTO moradia (id_pessoa, id_casa) VALUES (2, 2);

-- Carlos mora em dois lugares, e faz companhia a Maria na rua do SQL.
INSERT INTO moradia (id_pessoa, id_casa) VALUES (1, 2);

-- Julia mora na Avenida do banco de dados.
INSERT INTO moradia (id_pessoa, id_casa) VALUES (4, 1);
```

As instruções acima rodam no MySQL, mas devem funcionar em outros bancos de dados com modificações mínimas. Observe que não há deadlock porque o relacionamento é construído depois que as entidades a serem relacionadas já existem. Relacionamentos N-para-N são modelados por meio de uma tabela intermediária, que no caso acima é a tabela `moradia`.

Comment: Mas sua resposta trata de casos `[0,M]`. Se o AP tiver escrito a modelagem corretamente, existiria um momento de inconsistência entre a inserção de pessoas/casas que só seria resolvida quando fossem inseridas linhas de moradia. E concordo que a modelagem mais correta deveria ser `[0,M]`, parece-me que assim não fere as formas normais, mas `[1,M]` poderia ferir