# Relacionamento mutualmente exclusivo (MER)

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, relacionamento, entidade-relacionamento

Sei que existem várias formas de implementar esse modelo conceitual, mas **gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma** (caso exista alguma que se destaque)

> **Legenda**
>
> PK : Primary Key (chave primária);
>
> FK : Foreign Key (chave estrangeira)

### Veja um exemplo de relacionamento exclusivo

[image: relacionamento mutualmente exclusivo]

Retirado da [transparência desse livro](http://www.posselt.com.br/cepro/LV/aula7.pdf)

Entre as várias formas de implementar gostaria de destacar 2

### A primeira forma

Considere o uso de generalização/especialização nesse mesmo exemplo, desenhando assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora imagine que as entidades do modelo relacional vão se tornar tabelas do projeto lógico, e a PK da tabela **PESSOA** vai ser referenciada como FK na tabela **JURIDICO**, e assim vai ocorrer com as demais tabelas "filhas".

### Segunda Forma

Parecida com a primeira mas com inversão nas chaves, agora a chave PK da tabela **JURIDICO** vai ser referenciada na tabela **PESSOA** como uma FK e assim por diante.

## Observações Importantes a Considerar

Perceba que a entidade **VENDA** precisa está relacionada como uma pessoa jurídica ou uma pessoa física e não é possível compor um registro com as duas em simultâneo.

> Perceba que se a entidade **PESSOA** for suprimida então a entidade **VENDA** seria composta por 2 chaves estrangeiras sendo a primeira "CPF" FK referenciando o id da tabela **FISICA** e a segunda chave "CNPJ" FK referenciando o id da tabela **JURIDICA**.

Parece-me que fazer da forma acima gera é um erro de inconsistência, porque essas duas FK devem ser declaradas como opcionais, ou seja pode ser nulo.

Esse problema só da pra ser resolvido a nível de aplicação? ou da pra resolver essa inconsistência em nível de projeto conceitual?

[Nesse link é possível ver outro exemplo](http://www.blrdata.com.br/single-post/2016/03/19/Modelo-Conceitual-de-Dados-Aprenda-a-utilizar-os-principais-mecanismos-de-abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o) sobre relacionamento mutualmente exclusivo

Answer (score 2):

## Multiplexação de "chave estrangeira"

Cada forma tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, obviamente. Decidir qual é a melhor creio que você deva fazer em sua aplicação, desde que tendo conhecimento base para poder tomar essa decisão de escolha. Vou apresentar um caso recente que eu passei na empresa.

Trabalho num sistema de vendas, uma das nossas funcionalidades é que o vendedor possui conta-corrente. Assim, caso o vendedor queira dar um desconto a mais do que o limite de determinado produto, ele consome dessa conta-corrente e fecha a venda.

Um pedido desses pode por ventura ficar pendente, então entra a figura do supervisor. O supervisor, grosseiramente, aprova ou reprova pedidos realizados por vendedores. Além disso, caso o supervisor queira facilitar a vida de um vendedor para fechar uma compra de última hora, ele pode fazer uma transferência de sua conta-corrente para a conta-corrente do vendedor.

Tanto supervisor quanto vendedor são usuários do sistema.

Dito isso, a modelagem é muito semelhante imagem de **Generalização/especialização** que você colocou. Tenho a tabela `USUARIO`, `CONTACORRENTE` (sim, era tudojunto o nome original dessa tabela) com chave estrangeira não nula para `USUARIO`, `VENDEDOR` com chave estrangeira não nula para `USUARIO` e `SUPERVISOR` com chave estrangeira não nula para `USUARIO`. `SUPERVISOR` e `VENDEDOR` também possuem seus próprios códigos que não possuem relação com o código de usuário.

Bem, estava tudo tranquilo até chegar a seguinte customização:

> O comprador (no nosso sistema denominado de `CLIENTE`) também pode ter uma conta-corrente. Em compensação *não se pode exigir* que esse cliente possua usuário

Minha primeira reação foi propor a criação de usuários artificiais para manter esse relacionamento intacto. Posso dizer que ela não foi nem um pouco bem aceita? Tinha a ver com requisitos de negócio porque vendemos licenças de usuário para usar o sistema e essa minha ideia iria bagunçar legal esse controle.

Ok, próxima alternativa? Multiplexar a chave estrangeira.

Sim, bizarro, mas prático. Solucionou nossos problemas de modelagem. Propusemos uma migração de tal sorte que operações feitas na antiga `CONTACORRENTE` (agora transformada em *view*) afetassem apenas a imagem migrada na tabela novo `CONTA_CORRENTE` (sim, somos criativos :+1:).

> Vale dizer que erramos na *trigger* de migração que faria essa mágica? Esquecemos de testar inserções em batch, o que gera inconsistências malucas... mas obviamente que corrigimos esse erro "testado" em produção

A multiplexação funciona da seguinte forma:

1. tenho uma coluna que será a "chave estrangeira lógica" de alguma tabela;
2. tenho outra coluna que simplesmente indica para qual tabela a primeira coluna aponta.

A ideia veio da multiplexação baseado em comprimento de ondas do [MPλS](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/965082/), onde através das propriedades intrínsecas da transmissão de dados em fibras óticas o sistema sabe para qual destino direcionar.

O paralelo entre ondas de luz e linhas da tabela então ficou:

1. ambas possuem atributos multiplexadores (comprimento de onda/coluna multiplexadora);
2. ambas carregam dados que difere do atributo diferenciador (amplitude e fase da onda/as demais colunas da tupla).

De modo geral, a multiplexação que usei para representar esse relacionamento pode ser entendida através do seguinte esquema:

[image: [multiplexação de tabela]]

O triângulo não é uma entidade real, é apenas o "ponto" onde ocorre a multiplexação.

De modo geral, trabalhamos com bancos de dados de integridade ocasional. Torna mais fácil diversas operações no SQL-Server e temos a vantagem de que podemos ter estados inconsistentes temporários (mas não como o que o [SQLite permite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250757/64969)), então não nos preocupamos em colocar tentas `FOREIGN KEY` e `CHECK CONSTRAINTS` literais no banco. Deixamos a cargo de quem vai povoar os dados fazer isso de maneira coerente.

> Essa foi uma solução *real* para um problema que *aconteceu*. Não vou dizer que *todo problema* desse tipo você deve seguir esse caminho. Também não vou dizer para *sempre fugir* de uma solução dessas. Conhecimento é poder, use-o com sabedoria e parcimônia.

## Múltiplas chaves estrangeiras (*aka* modo 1 da pergunta)

Esse tipo de ligação pode gerar problemas, principalmente se for deliberadamente escolhido na criação do projeto evitar certos tipo de restrições para evitar *overheads* ([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/64969) e [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252982/64969)).

Tenho uma `pesquisa` que um `vendedor` vai aplicar aos `clientes` que atendam determinadas condições. No caso, as condições podem ser:

1. clientes que comprem determinadas representações (por exemplo, aqueles que compram Herbalife)
2. clientes que pertençam à determinada rota do vendedor
3. todos os clientes daquele vendedor
4. pergunta aplicável a vendedores sob a tutela de determinado supervisor
5. todos os clientes de todos os vendedores sem exceção

Isso pode ser modelado da seguinte forma:

```
APLICAÇÃO_PESQUISA:
  - CD_PESQUISA
  - CD_REPRESENTAÇÃO
  - CD_SUPERVISOR
  - CD_VENDEDOR
  - CD_SUPERVISOR
```

Por questão de velocidade para o último caso, foi criada uma *flag* adicional, um **identificador de todos**, sendo assim a estrutura final:

```
APLICAÇÃO_PESQUISA:
  - CD_PESQUISA
  - CD_REPRESENTAÇÃO
  - CD_SUPERVISOR
  - CD_VENDEDOR
  - CD_SUPERVISOR
  - ID_TODOS
```

Por uma questão de evitar *overheads*, não tem a restrição onde apenas um desses valores pode ser não nulo.

Bem, devido a essa "restrição frouxa" muito dependente do cadastro (e, pior ainda, se essas informações são importadas de um sistema externo, não temos demasiado controle sobre ela). Então, o que acontece com quem vai consumir essa informação?

A começo de conversa, essas restrições não estão formalmente documentadas em lugar algum, então a pobre alma que vai pegar o esquema e dele tentar extrair algum sentido vai levar em consideração que **qualquer subconjunto pode acontecer**. Exceto `ID_TODOS` marcado como verdade e alguém não nulo, isso não pode.

Então, acontece que a pobre alma que fez essa consulta, por ignorância, precisou levar em consideração:

1. se existir a representação daquele vendedor e o cliente ao mesmo tempo, mas o cliente não é atendido por aquele vendedor naquela representação, a aplicação de pesquisa vale para aquele vendedor e aquele cliente?
2. e se estiver marcado um vendedor e um supervisor que não faz parte de sua cadeia de supervisor nem dos supervisores de seu supervisor, devo tratar como uma espécie de `OU` ou o dado é inválido?

## Múltiplas chaves estrangeiras, o mais específico

Tem casos em que realmente se deseja que múltiplas chaves estrangeiras possam se ligar ou não a determinada estrutura, por *design* proposital mesmo. Não vou entrar muito no mérito aqui da estrutura e de suas chaves estrangeiras.

Imagina que você tenha 7 chaves estrangeiras. `CE0`, `CE1`, `CE2`, `CE3`, `CE4`, `CE5` e `CE6`. Existem 2<sup>7</sup>-1=127 maneiras distintas de que esse casamento possa ocorrer. Então, como decidir quais as formas mais específicas?

Podemos dizer que cada linha dessa tabela possui uma "bitagem" associada. Podemos representar como um número de 7 bits da seguinte maneira:

- se a coluna `CE_i` for não nula, o bit da posição `i` vale `1`
- se a coluna `CE_i` for nula, o bit da posição `i` vale `0`

Então, a "coluna artifical" `bitagem` pode apresentar o valor `0110111` (*little endian*), o que significa:

- `0` para a coluna `CE0`, portanto nula
- `1` para a coluna `CE1`, portanto não nula
- `1` para a coluna `CE2`, portanto não nula
- `0` para a coluna `CE3`, portanto nula
- `1` para a coluna `CE4`, portanto não nula
- `1` para a coluna `CE5`, portanto não nula
- `1` para a coluna `CE6`, portanto não nula

Para um valor de 64+32+16+4+2 = 118

Sobre essa `bitagem`, podemos definir uma tabela auxiliar que associa a `bitagem` a uma `prioridade` arbitrária, podendo então fazer qualquer ordenação desejada como sendo o "mais específico".

Apesar de essa formulação lembrar a taxonomia 1, como ele permite fazer múltiplas ligações ao mesmo tempo, não se encaixa nessa categoria.

Comment: Ficou muita boa a resposta, então pelo que entendi você fez da **primeira forma que apresentei** tem alguma justificativa por não ter feito da **segunda forma** ? quais decisões individuais ou coletivas levaram a optar por fazer da primeira forma?. Tenho visto em vários fóruns pessoas fazendo assim mas não entendo o motivo de ser melhor ou mais vantajoso a **primeira forma** em relação a **segunda forma**

Comment: Não fiz da primeira forma. A sua primeira forma exige duas colunas separaras, e eu fiz na mesma coluna a ligação. A decisão por não usar a sua segunda forma foi que eram entidades imiscíveis

Comment: Como eu tentei deixar claro na resposta (talvez não tenha ficado), essa solução foi extremamente não ortodoxa. Não é um padrão para aplicar em todos os lugares. Conheça as suas ferramentas e para cada caso use a mais adequada