# Qual o significado de Overhead em projeto físico de banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, stored-procedures, índices, overhead

Acabo de ler sobre projeto físico e ajuste de banco de dados e não consegui entender o conceito de overhead, e consequentemente não consegui entender o que o autor do livro quis explicar.

Entendo previamente por overhead como sendo uma **sobrecarga** ou **sobrescrita**.

> Autor do livro.
>
> > À remoção e criação de novos índices é um **overhead** que pode ser justificado em relação as melhorias no desempenho.

Entendo e me fez parecer coerente que a criação de índices nas tabelas, ajuda na velocidade das consultas feitas nela, mas não entendo como o contrário (a remoção dos índices) ajuda no desempenho, como afirma o autor.

#### Observações

Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198252/o-que-%C3%A9-overhead) o autor afirma que não importa muito o contexto em que a palavra é usada, nesse meu contexto procede essa resposta?

Caso a comunidade entenda que a minha pergunta possa ser respondida pela resposta citada acima, então irei remove-la.

**Livro**: Sistemas de banco de dados, 2011. Elmasri R, Nevathe B, Cap 20, pg 495.

Comment: **_Overhead_** não tem nada a ver (diretamente) com **sobrescrita**. Mas **sobrescrita** pode causar um **_overhead_**

Comment: Índices ajudam em pesquisas mas podem piorar operações de insert, update ou delete pois tem constrains associadas (verificações a grosso modo) isso gera um processamento a mais (overhead).

Comment: Restrições geram mais processamentos e mais processamentos pode ser traduzido ou interpretado como overhead? é isso @rray? nesse caso a remoção de algum índice que esteja causando esse aumento do processamento, pode sofrer influencia direta dessas restrições, se for isso acho que entendi.

Comment: Qualquer processamento além do trivial é _overhead_. No caso, verificar se uma coluna é não nula gera um processamento além da inserção

Comment: Costumo traduzir como "sobrepeso" ou "peso extra". "Sobrecarga" já existe e significa outra coisa no contexto de programação.