# Em qual tabela fica a chave estrangeira em uma relação 1 para 1?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-estrangeira, cardinalidade

Em um relacionamento SQL de duas tabelas 1 para 1, existe alguma regra que defina em qual tabela a chave estrangeira vai ficar?

Comment: sua pergunta é bem genérica; precisa entender sua necessidade para dizer, por exemplo, que um `usuario` terá um atributo que fará referência a um `endereco`. Mas a ideia é você pensar que se _faz sentido a **tabela X** possuir um item da **tabela Y**_.. se sim, `tabela X` terá uma _chave estrangeira_ da `tabela Y`

Comment: Relação 1:1 é vago pois diversas razões fazem sua implementação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pergunta é boa e me fez pensar em algo que a gente nem sempre se dá conta.

Aprendemos (eu acho) que o N é o contradomínio e é nele que fica a chave estrangeira. Não tenho estudo tão formal de álgebra relacional e posso estar falando alguma besteira, mas o uso normal do relacionamento impede o lado do domínio, o 1, afinal você pode ter vários. Vou descartar aí alguma implementação de banco de dados que permite várias chaves estrangeiras na mesma linha (isso pode até ser simulado passando por cima do SGDB). E sabemos que o N:M pode ter chaves estrangeiras nos dois lados. Ou seja, só não podemos usar chave estrangeira se ela tiver que ser repetida na mesma linha. Acho que esta é a regra (note que estou falando de regra, de algo que não pode ser quebrado, não falo de boa prática que depende de contexto).

Por isso que há casos que você precisa criar uma tabela de amarração entre duas tabelas para que a chave se comporte como 1:N e M:1 do outro lado.

Se a regra não for aproximadamente essa então provavelmente ela é ruim, mas duvido porque ela foi definida em época que as definições da computação eram feitas de forma científica, não como hoje em dia que alguém escreve uma abobrinha qualquer em um blog, não tem comprovação alguma, e todo mundo sai repetindo como se fosse um axioma. Aí criam termos malucos como "NoSQL", "responsivo", "serverless" e tantos outros :) A não ser que eu tenha interpretado algo errado e não percebi.

Então em 1:1 podemos ter chave dos dois lados, porque é garantido que não há repetição dessa chave na mesma linha.

Um exemplo é uma `pessoa` que tem um papel de `cliente`, portanto um relacionamento 1:1. Se você quer partindo da `pessoa` pegar os dados do `cliente` coloca uma chave estrangeira ali e partindo do `cliente`, quer saber quem é a `pessoa` por trás dele coloca uma chave estrangeira ali. Se acessa partindo de um dos lados qualquer, tanto faz do ponto de vista lógico em qual vai a chave estrangeira, mas pode dar diferente por questões de otimização. A escolha certa pode evitar a criação de um índice secundário, exemplo: se parte da `pessoa`, basta ter a chave estrangeira para o `cliente` e no `cliente` só tem a chave primária para achá-lo. Se não tiver nada na `pessoa` a única forma de achar rápido quem é o papel de `cliente` daquela `pessoa` é acessando a chave estrangeira que indica quem é a `pessoa` lá. Ou é lento ou tem um índice secundário, a não ser que a chave primária seja igual à chave da `pessoa`, o que faz que sequer precise de chave estrangeira, e quem sabe o 1:1 esteja errado.

Mas se quer saber em qual lado usar em um exemplo concreto só vendo esse caso concreto, poder usar nos dois lados não quer dizer que deve, e escolher o lado depende da necessidade. Sem o caso concreto só dá para responder do ponto de vista da álgebra que permite dos dois lados.

Entenda mais sobre em [Qual a vantagem de um relacionamento 1:1?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essa conversa de ter um modelo 1:1 (e não o modelo 1:0..1) me lembrou da questão sobre ["deadlock" conceitual no MER](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250416/64969). Para uma linha existir, a outra precisa existir e vice-versa

Answer (score -3):

Resumindo: A chave estrangeira vai fica sempre na tabela que vai buscar a outra ou seja a tabela que contem algum campo identificando ou referindo outra tabela.